# How to disable SSL verification for urlretrieve?

Tags: python, urllib2

A similar question had been asked a couple times around SO, but the solutions are for `urlopen`. That function takes an optional `context` parameter which can accept a pre-configured SSL context. `urlretrieve` does not have this parameter. How can I bypass SSL verification errors in the following call?

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    "http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/files/1.3.1/libjpeg-turbo-1.3.1.tar.gz/download", 
    destFolder+"/libjpeg-turbo.tar.gz")
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This solution worked as well for me: before making the call to the library, define the default SSL context:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
# urllib.request.urlretrieve(...)
```

Source: http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2016/01/python-certificate-verified-failed/

Comment: The solution above works just fine for python 3.7.4 on mac (installed with pyenv)

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be possible with `urlretrieve` (in Python >=2.7.9, or Python >=3.0).

The [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package is recommended as a replacement.

Edited to add: the context parameter has been added to the code, even though it isn't mentioned in the documentation! Hat-tip @Sushisource

Comment: This is possible at least as of 2.7.14

Comment: @Sushisource: I can't see any evidence that is true, but I would love to be proven wrong. Please post a new answer with a link to some documentation or code that backs it up.

Comment: It's not in the docs, but the urlretrieve function happily accepted a context parameter in 2.7.14

Comment: Wow, you are right. It was [added 3 years ago](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b206473ef8a7abe9abf5ab8776ea3bcb90adc747) but the documentation doesn't seem to have been updated.