# Twilio - Phone Lookup requests.exceptions.SSLError

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, twilio, urllib3

I'm using Twilio's [phone number lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v2-api) (`client.lookups.v2.phone_numbers`) for Python. I will *only* be using this on my local machine to validate phone numbers.

Here's my code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "••••••••••••••••••••••••••"
auth_token = "••••••••••••••••••••••••••"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

phone_number = client.lookups.v2.phone_numbers("+14159929960").fetch()
print(phone_number)
```

I put the full error stack at the bottom because it's a huge wall of text.

In the [Troubleshooting Certificate Errors from the Twilio REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007853433-Troubleshooting-Certificate-Errors-from-the-Twilio-REST-API) page, they suggest that I:

> download the latest Mozilla-provided CA certificate bundle in PEM format from curl's website, which already includes our new root certificate. The specific certificate required from the bundle is DigiCert Global Root CA, which is directly available for download in CRT format from DigiCert.

so I downloaded and installed the [CA certificate bundle](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) as well as the [DigiCert Global Root CA](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm), but it threw the same errors.

I'm pretty sure that the problem exists in `python3.9/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py` with `result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)`. I looked around for a few hours and I could *not* find the `SSL_do_handshake` def to see where the holdup is.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31297747/7668146) didn't work on my macbook, I just couldn't import the files into my keychain.
- I would like to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36600583/7668146) solution, but I don't know where I would put `ssl.CERT_NONE`. I believe Twilio uses `urllib3`, but I can't find a place to put it.
- This answer involves using `requests`, which I am not using.
- Most answers are addressing issues with ```requests``, so there isn't much that helps there.
- Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027418/openssl-python-requests-error-certificate-verify-failed) question inspired me to try this bash script:

```
curl -X GET 'https://lookups.twilio.com/v2/PhoneNumbers/+14159929960' \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

And it worked! **So this seems to be a Python issue and not a certificate issue.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 437, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1835, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1570, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 51, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 337, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 345, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 443, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 637, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lookups.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/PhoneNumbers/+14159929960 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/twiliophonelookup.py", line 16, in <module>
    phone_number = client.lookups.v2.phone_numbers("+14159929960").fetch()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/rest/lookups/v2/phone_number.py", line 153, in fetch
    payload = self._version.fetch(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/base/version.py", line 72, in fetch
    response = self.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/base/version.py", line 39, in request
    return self.domain.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/base/domain.py", line 38, in request
    return self.twilio.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 142, in request
    return self.http_client.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/http/http_client.py", line 89, in request
    response = session.send(prepped_request, **settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lookups.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/PhoneNumbers/+14159929960 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Comment: When you say you couldn't import the certificate to your Keychain, that seems like the problem here. What did you do and why didn't it work?

Comment: I'm on MacOS Catalina, when I import cacert.cer into my keychains, nothing happens. I just saw that I have DigiCertGlobalRootCA.cer in mykeychains though. However, I still don't know why it works with Bash and not Python. If I were better with Bash I'd use it.

Comment: Under the hood, Twilio Python uses requests, might [this answer help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71812035/28376)? Particularly setting the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` to the downloaded SSL certs.

Comment: Yes, that did it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to philnash and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71812035/28376), the solution is this:

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<path to pem>
```

I tried a couple, but the one that worked was:

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cacert.cer
```